# What is the advantage of --asm option in solc, how can we compile the contract using --asm option in online remix tool?

Tags: remix

Kindly guide me the advantage of --asm option in solc compared to run-time and deployed opcode facility in REMIX, and how can we compile the contract on online REMIX tool using --asm option?

Zulfi.